# Cannot use global variable in NodeJS MySQL

Tags: javascript, node.js

I cannot access the upcoming_matches array inside the MySQL query callback, how come?

I'm greeted with a 'TypeError: Cannot read property '1' of null' error message on the console.log(upcoming_matches[1]); line which indicates that the variable is being reset for some reason (a guess, I'm not very experienced with Javascript)?

```
var regex = regex code..

while ((upcoming_matches = regex.exec(body)) != null) {
    HLTVID = upcoming_matches[1].split("-");    

    connection.query('SELECT * FROM `csgo_matches` WHERE HLTVID=' + HLTVID[0], function(err, rows, fields) {
        if (err) throw err;
        console.log(upcoming_matches[1]);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because at the moment the callback passed to `connection.query` is executed, the `while` loop already finished and `upcoming_matches` is `null` (because that's the condition for the `while` loop to stop).

`connection.query` is **asynchronous**.

See [Why is my variable unaltered after I modify it inside of a function? - Asynchronous code reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23667086/why-is-my-variable-unaltered-after-i-modify-it-inside-of-a-function-asynchron)